# Parameterizing actions for Compositions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have recognized that certain tables occur at quite a few places in my application and am attempting to package them as compositions. This is an excerpt of what I came up with:

```
<p:dataTable var="permission" value="#{permissionList}"
  id="permissionTable">
    <p:column headerText="Edit" rendered="#{showEdit}" style="width:50px">
        <p:rowEditor />
        <p:commandLink action="#{removeAction}" update="permissionTable">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

There are currently three parameters:

- `permissionList` is the table content
- `showEdit` to turn on and off inline editing options which are not feasible at all places.
- `removeAction` because removing a permission may mean removing it from a role, a subject or deleting it, depending on the context.

Including the permissionTable now looks like this:

```
<ui:include src="compositions/permissionTable.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="permissionList"
      value="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.role.permissions}" />
    <ui:param name="showEdit" value="#{true}" />
    <ui:param name="removeAction"
      value="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.removePermission(permission)}" />
</ui:include>
```

Sadly, there is a problem with the `removeAction` parameter. Whatever I pass in seems to be null when included. I do recognize using a contextual parameter name (`permission`) is probably similar to begging for trouble.

So how could I either

- Get my approach above to work?
- Implement actions properly for compositions? I somehow suspect I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: At the moment I don't have a solution for the setup above. But does it have to be an include or could you also define a custom component (cc:interface, cc:implementation)? The parameters would be defined in the interface and you could use something like `<myComp:permissionTable removeAction=#{xyz}/>`. Or is this approach also failing?

Comment: I simply didn't know about custom components, I have been using JSF for only roundabout 2 weeks now. So by making this thing a component parameter passing should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagined something like this:

*permissionTable.xhtml (placed into JSF's resource folder)*

```
<html
namespaces go here>
<cc:interface></cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable var="permission" value="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.role.permissions}" id="permissionTable">
        <p:column headerText="Edit" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}" style="width:50px">
            <p:rowEditor />
            <p:commandLink action="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.removePermission(permission)}" update="permissionTable">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

---

*the page uses*

```
<myComp:permissionTable rendered="#{showEdit}" />
```

Comment: Where do the `cc` and `myComp` namespaces come from? And where is the resource folder? I am using a maven prototype and it comes with a setup containing `webapp/META-INF`, `webapp/WEB-INF` and `web-resources`. I would assume it should be the last folder, but where would this be configured so I can check?

Comment: Hi, just take a look at [True Abstraction: Composite UI Components in JSF 2.0 -- Part 1](http://137.254.16.27/enterprisetechtips/entry/true_abstraction_composite_ui_components) and [JSF 2.0 TLD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html). There are a lot of tutorials around - no need to copy and paste it here. ;) Gruß, Dennis

Comment: True, thanks a bunch. Its just that the JSF tutorials on the web are so ... diverse, I am not always sure which one to follow.